# How to check if a file exists, and if so append a number to the file name

Tags: python

Hi I'm trying to create multiple samples from a signal. To do this, when the fft is drawn i'm also outputting the frequency and the amplitude to a csv file. The problem with this though is that I'm only making one sample because the output file just gets overwritten every time. What I want to do is check if the file 'output.csv' exists already, and if so append incrementing numbers for each new file along the lines of 'output1.csv' 'output2.csv' and so on. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
    def draw_fft(self):
        self.plot_fft[0].set_data([self.freq, self.iq_fft])
        self.sp_fft.set_xlim(self.freq.min(), self.freq.max())
        self.sp_fft.set_ylim([self.iq_fft.min()-10, self.iq_fft.max()+10])
        # for debugging print(self.freq,self.iq_fft)
        freqOut = np.array(self.freq)
        amplOut = np.array(self.iq_fft)
        output = np.column_stack((freqOut.flatten(),amplOut.flatten())
        # where the file check should occur
        np.savetxt('output.csv',output,delimiter=',')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure you could do that. How about instead appending something more informative to the filename e.g. the date and time at the moment.

This way you don't have to check for the presence of a file.

```
import datetime as dt 

def draw_fft(self):
    ...
    outputfilename = 'output_{}.csv'.format( dt.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') )
    np.savetxt(outputfilename, output, delimiter=',')
```

Comment: Thanks this (though slightly messy) works really well (and I only have to impress my project partners by finally having useful data for her to parse through haha) By the way, what can I cite you as?

Comment: You're most welcome. Feel free to use the code as you wish. You needn't site me, but if you so desire you may include a (shortened) link to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15255919/42346 perhaps as a comment in your source code.

Answer (score 6):

```
from os.path import isfile

sequence = ""
filename = "output%s.csv"

while isfile(filename % sequence):
    sequence = int(sequence or 0) + 1
filename = filename % sequence
```

Note that this may be subject to a race condition if another process or thread is trying to create a file in the same directory using the same base name and method.

Answer (score 1):

To check if a file exists, use the `os.path.isfile` function:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile

Comment: is there a simple way to append like 'output' + num + '.csv'?

Comment: You can use string formatting: `"output%d.csv" % num` (where num should be a number)... Or do it like this: `name = "output" + str(num) + ".csv"`